# How to get data from database based on particular month?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have 3 html `select` tag to search data from mysql database based on date. Using these 3 select tag user can select Year, Month and Zone Name (zone_id).

After select these 3 tag option value I am creating a variable to search data based on date:

```
$selected_year = isset($_POST['year']) ? (int) $_POST['year'] : date("Y");
$selected_month = isset($_POST['month']) ? (int) $_POST['month'] : date("n");
$selected_zone = isset($_POST['zone']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['zone']) : '';

$search_date = date('d'.'-'.$selected_month.'-'.$selected_year);
$search_date = strtotime($search_date);
```

This `$search-date` variable is printing user selected month as php strtotime(). eg : 1470866400

Now I have a table called `client_pay_bill` and there are a column name `conn_date`. This `conn_date` column value is store various month as php `strtotime()`. For eg : 1467324000 or 1470866400

Now I want to get value for specific month. For eg :

If user selected year and month is generate a August, 2016 timestamp then the query will be return only this August, 2016 data. How can I do this ?

**Sql Query :**

```
$get_client = "SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount, cbp.pay_amount, c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date 
FROM clients AS c 
LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id 
LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id 
LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE c.uid = '$uid' AND c.is_active = 1 AND c.conn_date <= '$search_date' ";

if($selected_zone != "all") {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id != '' ";
} elseif($selected_zone == "all") {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id != '' ";
} else {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id = '$selected_zone' ";
}

$get_client .= "  ORDER BY c.client_id DESC ";
$get_client = mysqli_query($conn, $get_client);
```

**Update :**

**3 select tag are bellow :**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="year" id="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Select Year-- </option>                        
        <?php
        for ($y=2013; $y<=2017; $y++) {
            if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] == $y) {
                $selected = 'selected = "selected"';
            } elseif( !isset($_POST['year']) && date('Y') == $y ) {
                $selected = 'selected = "selected"';
            } else {
                $selected = '';
            }
            echo "<option value='$y' $selected>$y</option>";
        }
        ?>                                        
    </select>           
</div>                                      
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="month" id="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Select Month-- </option>                        
        <?php 
        $months = array('January', 'February','March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July ',   'August',  'September',  'October',  'November', 'December');

        $mcount = 1;
        foreach($months as $month) {
            if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == $mcount) {
                $selected = 'selected = "selected" ';
            } elseif(!isset($_POST['month']) && date('n') == $mcount ) {
                $selected = 'selected = "selected" ';
            } else {
                $selected = '';
            }
            echo "<option value='$mcount' $selected>$month</option>";
            $mcount++;                                        
        }

        ?>                                        
    </select>                    
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="zone" id="" class="form-control">                                                
    <?php
    $query_zone = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT zone_id, zone_name FROM zone WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY zone_id DESC");
    $query_zone_num = mysqli_num_rows($query_zone);
    if($query_zone_num == 0) {
        echo "<option value=''>No zone added</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value=''>Select Zone</option>";  
        echo '<option value="all" selected="selected">All Zone</option>';
    }
    while($result_zone = mysqli_fetch_array($query_zone)) {
        $zone_id = (int) $result_zone['zone_id'];
        $zone_name = htmlspecialchars($result_zone['zone_name']);

        if(isset($_POST['zone']) && $_POST['zone'] == $zone_id) {
            $selected = 'selected = "selected" ';
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }
        echo "<option value='$zone_id' $selected>$zone_name</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>                    
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saving date in unix time stamp format in your client_pay_bill table ?

Comment: I am using mysql NOW() to insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the MySQL handle it:

```
$get_client = "
  SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount, cbp.pay_amount, c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date 
  FROM clients AS c 
  LEFT JOIN zone
    ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id 
  LEFT JOIN package
    ON package.package_id = c.package_id 
  LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp
    ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id 
  WHERE c.uid = '$uid'
    AND c.is_active = 1
    AND MONTH(c.conn_date) = $selected_month
    AND YEAR(c.conn_date) = $selected_year
";
```

Please try it and check if it's what you want.

Edit, try this:

```
$get_client = "
  SELECT *
  FROM clients AS c
  WHERE MONTH(c.conn_date) = $selected_month
    AND YEAR(c.conn_date) = $selected_year
";
```

Comment: Let me try with it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the variables the right way, concatenating it with the query string. I forgot about that, sorry. Or maybe it's alright to use without concatenating them, because all variable within double quotes in a string in PHP are replaced for it's value.

Comment: How is your date being stored in database? What's the format?

Comment: Well, I using mysql NOW() function to insert date value and I have updated my question. Please check the how can I create the data using these year and date select tag.

Comment: When you post the form, does the `$selected_year` and `$selected_month` has a value? You can check by entering `var_dump($selected_year);` `var_dump($selected_month);` `exit();` after getting the values with `$_POST`.

Comment: Yes It's showing me 2016 and 8 as year and month. Note : in db conn_date is sotred date as timestamp.

Comment: I've edited the answer, try the code after `Edit, try this:` to check what's wrong.

Comment: `echo $get_client;` `exit();` and past here the result to check if the string is correct.

Comment: SELECT * FROM clients AS c WHERE MONTH(c.conn_date) = 8 AND YEAR(c.conn_date) = 2016

Comment: Could you please share one of the stored dates in `conn_date` column?

Comment: It's storing date time using mysql NOW(). The value is something like this : 1470866400

Comment: Alright, then you need to store the date in a different format to work with my solution. I thought you were storing it with the pre defined `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. If, when you store the date in DB, you use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1470866400);` it will store `2016-08-10 19:00:00` and you will be able to use my solution. But I'll edit the answer again with another try that I just thought

Comment: Yes, Now I am planing to use con_date column type = DATETIME()

Comment: The other solution I thought will not work, you will need to modify the date in you DB to match the pattern `2016-08-10 19:00:00` and then you will be able to filter with `MONTH(c.conn_date)` and `YEAR(c.conn_date)`

Comment: If you are using PHP to store the date in DB, you can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` or you just set the column in the DB to be the `preset` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but then you need to change the `type` to `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $get_client = "SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount,cbp.pay_amount, c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date FROM clients AS c  LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id  LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id WHERE c.uid = '$uid' AND c.is_active = 1 AND Month(c.conn_date)=$selected_month.
```

Try like this

Comment: select * from log_time l where MONTH(l.created_date_time)=MONTH(str_to_date('2016-07-20', '%Y-%m-%d'))

Comment: can you share your table

Comment: the column name I am searching for date is `conn_date`and it's saving php timestamp() data.

Comment: MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.created_date_time)>$startmonth and YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1.created_date_time))>$startyear

Answer (score 0):

try this it would match for month and year

```
$get_client = "SELECT cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, cbp.due_amount,cbp.pay_amount, c.is_active, c.client_id, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.monthly_bill, c.bill_date FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id WHERE c.uid = '$uid' AND c.is_active = 1 AND YEAR(c.conn_date) = ".$selected_year." AND MONTH(c.conn_date) = ".$selected_month." ";
```